# PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_NO_TMP_DIR - assumed 'UPLOAD_NO_TMP_DIR'

Tags: php, image, oop

I keep getting this error:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_NO_TMP_DIR - assumed
>   'UPLOAD_NO_TMP_DIR' test/includes/image.php on line 157

And here's the block of code it's pointing to at line 157:

```
public static function find_by_id($id=0){
    global $database;
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ". self::$table_name ." WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($id) ." LIMIT 1");
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}
```

Many lines above that, in this class I have this chunk of code:

```
protected $upload_errors = array(
  UPLOAD_ERR_OK         => "No errors.", 
  UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.", 
  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.", 
  UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    => "Partial upload.", 
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    => "No file.", 
  UPLOAD_NO_TMP_DIR     => "No temp dir.", 
  UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Can't write to disk.", 
  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => "File upload stopped by extension."
);
```

I can't figure this out and would love it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You most likely dont have access to protected variable `$upload_errors` in the area of code around line 157

Comment: How do I correct that, if that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) it should be `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR` and not `UPLOAD_NO_TMP_DIR`.

Comment: Wow!  It looks like you were right!  I've been burdened by this many times and never caught that!  Thank you Nigel Ren!  I am confident that was the problem, because I made the change and deleted the error_log.  Then I ran the program and saw that it didn't pop back up.  I changed it back to the old way, the wrong way, and it caused that error to show up again.  I just wanted to be absolutely sure.  So, THANK YOU!